# What's the point of downloading the source jars in a grails project?

Tags: eclipse, grails, jar, spring-tool-suite

I've noticed that in eclipse if you Right click on a project -> Grails Tools -> You have the option to 'Download Source Jars'.

What is the point of this and what are some common reasons as to why you would want to do this?

Grails 2.2.3

Edit:
I'm not even sure what grails does instead of that.

Comment: I'm not a grails person, but I often like to look at the source code of libraries if I'm debugging...

Comment: @jbutler483: Oh that's definitely not a reasonable inference. My Java coding is typically at work, where we have a fairly custom environment...

Comment: you did say yourself you're not a grails person, that was all :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many (most) libraries (JARs, "artifacts" in the Maven terminology) publish a sources archive alongside their binary artifacts in the repositories. This can be useful for Eclipse to show you the Javadoc and source code when you're using the library in your projects. As @JonSkeet commented above, it's very useful to have source code available directly in the IDE when using a library.

By default, Grails does **not** download the sources for artifacts; this option triggers it to do so and attach the sources to the binary JARs.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with E-Riz.

Here are the reasons I use the sources:

- i want to have a deeper understanding of how the library works when debugging my own depending code
- i want to find a possible bug in the library, so I can fork it and apply my own patch. i will possibly share this with the maintainers as a pull request if I'm willing to spend that much time on it.
- i want to find out what logging systems it uses that might be poorly documented, so I can see better what their code is doing during runtime, to troubleshooting complicated problems.